# GoogleMapを使ってカーナビ機能を実現したい

Tags: android

androidアプリで、GoogleMapを使ったカーナビ機能を実現できないか調査を行っています。

現在地から目的地までの経路は、Googleの経路検索APIで取得できました。
取得したデータの中に、経路の緯度経度があるので、それを使ってマップ上に線を引くところまではできました。

目的地に向かって進んでいったときに、進んだところまでの線を別の色で線を引きたいのですが、方法がわかりません。経路上における現在地の緯度経度を求める方法がわかりません。

スタート地点～目的地までのルートがセットされている`List<LatLng>`を使って、スタート地点～Nメートル進んだ地点までのルートを、`List<LatLng>`で取得したいのです。

求める方法を教えて頂けないでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: deviceにもよるけど、GPSしか付いてないならGPSから取るしかないんじゃない？
加速度センサ併用して、カーナビlikeに現在地を推測することもできるとは思うけど...
既存のスマホ向けナビアプリがそれを実現してないことから、何らかの高いハードルがあるんじゃないかな？

Comment: 既に実現されていますよ。例えばこんな記事があります。[カーナビなんて不要！　GoogleMAPのナビゲーション](https://aoshi-s.net/googlemap-navi/) 作りたい機能とは別かもしれませんが。

Comment: Google Map の中に Geolocation API というのがあるようです[Google Maps Platform APIの種類と機能](https://www.zenrin-datacom.net/business/gmapsapi/function/index.html)。 いくつか解説記事[Google Maps JavaScript Api 現在位置を取得するサンプル (Geolocation API)](https://kishiken.com/jq/google-maps-javascript-api-1.html) [Geolocation APIでPCやスマホの位置情報を取得する](https://qiita.com/akkey2475/items/81f4f94f17bfe5c7ce42) [GoogleMapで現在地にマーカーを表示する](https://qiita.com/akkey2475/items/29a5e5ab0e0ca04f4169) がありますが、今年5月に[プラン変更](https://maps.multisoup.co.jp/blog/2963/)があり、そのまま使えるかどうかは要確認ですね。

Answer (score 1):

自己レスです。

Googleが提供している android-maps-utils の SphericalUtilクラスの関数 computeHeading() と computeOffset() を使うことで、スタート地点から指定した距離まで進んだところまでの座標配列を取得することができました！